# Perl error when try to install "screen"

Tags: linux, perl, apt-get, gnu-screen

I need to install screen on my server (Debian 8, Kernel 3.16.0). But when I
type `apt-get install screen` (with root), I see this:

> "Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/^(.*?)(\)?\${ <-- HERE ([^{}]+)}(.*)$/ at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Question.pm line 72.
>   Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/\${ <-- HERE ([^}]+)}/ at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Config.pm line 30."

And not work.
I dont know what I can search because I try Google but its different.
How to fix it?
thanks so much

EDIT: I try now `aptget` update and upgrade and I see the same error. But, after I try to install screen and it give me no error, but screen not work.

Comment: Your error is a text message. Please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15158357) and add the text of your message. An image of text is a horrible way to share information.

Comment: i edit now, but the error is disappeared when i do update and upgrade, but screen does not work anyway, There is a log file of the screen?

Comment: This is a deprecation warning, not an error. If stuff is not working then this message is **not the reason**. It's documented [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldiag.html#Unescaped-left-brace-in-regex-is-deprecated%2c-passed-through-in-regex%3b-marked-by-%3c---HERE-in-m%2f%25s%2f) and will likely be a syntax error and thus a fatal error from Perl 5.26. It was [deprecated with Perl 5.22](http://perldoc.perl.org/perl5220delta.html#A-literal-%22%7b%22-should-now-be-escaped-in-a-pattern). At most, this tells us that you have a very recent Perl in your Debian 8.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include **all the output you get**.

Comment: I think the problem of perl is resolved after using "upd and upg" but I do not understand why screen does not work, does not give me any kind of mistake, just nothing happens, I press send and returns me the # saying nothing

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the perl code in this file has a regexp that triggers a warning with the recent perl you have.
The source file comes from the `debconf` package:

```
$ dpkg -S /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Question.pm
debconf: /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Question.pm
```

The problem has probably been already fixed (at least it is on `debconf-1.5.58ubuntu1` on Ubuntu 16.04). So you should try to upgrade that package (and all available updates by the way).

Comment: yes, i upgrade and now work(i think..) but for the screen, when i try to start a screen, it immediatly stop without saying anything, idk if is about perl o something also

Comment: @gianni carlo, "*it give me no error, but screen not work*" and "*it immediatly stop without saying anything*" do not form a sufficient description of the problem. Besides, do you really want to debug `screen`?

Comment: @ikegami I know, but I do not know what else to say, simply, a vps newly formatted, after doing updates, I installed screen and does not work, apart from the problem mentioned above, it has now solved by another update, there 'is nothing else, I came out no mistake, I do not know where to go looking for a "log" file to see why it will not start, nothing, I know nothing, I know this is a little, but I know nothing if you tell me what to check in order to get other information, I will report immediately

Comment: Start with determining the error code returned. Either way, the next step is to load `sceen` in the debugger and debug it. But I'm guessing you don't know how to do that. It's not something we can do for you. (If I'm wrong, what's stopping you?)

Comment: then, when I give the command screen, reappears me "#" as if it would work, but it really does not start nothing, I know nothing of the debugger

Comment: In `bash`, the exit code of the last program it executed is found in `$?`. We can't teach you to debug.

Comment: it's embarrassing, I'm sorry but unfortunately do not understand much English, what you mean by "the exit code of the last program it executed is found in the $?"?

Comment: @ikegami lol, i fail the command, now when i type the right command,the console becomes all black and then immediately appears:[screen is terminating] and #

Comment: Run `echo $?` after `screen` exits

Comment: i try and appear : 0

Comment: If you get an empty screen (well, just a new prompt '#') I suspect that screen is just working as expected. What did you expect?